# How to force the bootstrap 4 columns to adjust the height per the inside content in a row?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to show the number of links records in col-md-6 using while loop. When i display all the link content and if the height of one col-md-6 is less then other parallel column then it creates a white space. Please suggest me how to remove these white spaces.
[Here the problem screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsk4q.png)

I want to remove the white space below the first column

The Full Code After While Loop Execution:

```
<div class="row container pl-5">

          <div class="col-lg-6 links pt-0">
          <h4>ACTIVATIONS LINKS</h4>
        <ol>

        <li><a target="_blank" href="t">Omni - Verizon Activation</a></li>

                  </ol>
          <br />
        </div> <!----Col END--->



                   <div class="col-lg-6 links pt-0">
          <h4>VERIZON CUSTOMER SERVICE LINKS</h4>
        <ol>

        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/featured/better-matters/?map=4glte#maps">Interactive Coverage Map</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/switch-to-verizon/">Check Number Port-In Status</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="fgh">How to Complete an Assumption of Liability</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/trip-planner-tool/#/tripPlanner">Trip Planner - International Rate Plans</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/my-verizon/">My Verizon</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/discount-program/">Verizon Discount Enrollment</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/military/">Military Discount Enrollment</a></li>


        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/solutions-and-services/hum/">HUM Service Info</a></li>

                  </ol>
         </div> <!----Col END--->
</div> <!----ROW END--->
```

Comment: remove the br tag ?

Comment: the code you shared is not helpful - kindly share minimal code which replicates the issue and someone from the community will help.

Comment: The br tag create a one line break after column , its no the problem # Daid Bray

Comment: the break is the result of the two columns in the top being contained in a single row. That row ends before the next row begins. You can place your content into a single row to make it more compact.

Answer (score 0):

The break is the result of the two columns in the top being contained in a single row. That row ends before the next row begins. You can place your content into a single row to make it more compact.

You may need to expand the snippet to see this in action.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row container pl-5">

  <div class="col-lg-6 links pt-0">
    <h4>ACTIVATIONS LINKS</h4>
    <ol>

      <li><a target="_blank" href="t">Omni - Verizon Activation</a></li>

    </ol>
    <h4>ACTIVATIONS LINKS</h4>
    <ol>

      <li><a target="_blank" href="t">Omni - Verizon Activation</a></li>

    </ol>
    <br />
  </div>
  <!----Col END--->



  <div class="col-lg-6 links pt-0">
    <h4>VERIZON CUSTOMER SERVICE LINKS</h4>
    <ol>

      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/featured/better-matters/?map=4glte#maps">Interactive Coverage Map</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/switch-to-verizon/">Check Number Port-In Status</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="fgh">How to Complete an Assumption of Liability</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/trip-planner-tool/#/tripPlanner">Trip Planner - International Rate Plans</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/my-verizon/">My Verizon</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/discount-program/">Verizon Discount Enrollment</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/military/">Military Discount Enrollment</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/solutions-and-services/hum/">HUM Service Info</a></li>

    </ol>

    <h4>VERIZON CUSTOMER SERVICE LINKS</h4>
    <ol>

      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/featured/better-matters/?map=4glte#maps">Interactive Coverage Map</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/switch-to-verizon/">Check Number Port-In Status</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="fgh">How to Complete an Assumption of Liability</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/trip-planner-tool/#/tripPlanner">Trip Planner - International Rate Plans</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/my-verizon/">My Verizon</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/discount-program/">Verizon Discount Enrollment</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/military/">Military Discount Enrollment</a></li>


      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.verizonwireless.com/solutions-and-services/hum/">HUM Service Info</a></li>

    </ol>
  </div>
  <!----Col END--->
</div>
<!----ROW END--->
```

Comment: I am fetching the record using while loop . This will work only for manual case.

Comment: Whether you use a loop or not you are placing the listis in columns and rowsm so just place them in a different structure. Reorganize your loop to grab `activation links` and `other customer service links` and place both loops in the same column. Then grab `Verizon Customer Service Links` and `How Tos & What To Dos` and put those in the same column. Wrap all of that in a single row. If you want to share the while loop code we can take a look at it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row.container{
   -webkit-columns: 2;
   columns: 2;
   -webkit-column-width: auto;
   column-width: auto;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
   display:block;
}
.row.container .links{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.